# Join these two objects together?

Tags: modeling, workflow

[image: https://imgur.com/oXqFiYP]

I'm trying to join the bottom of this arcade stick to the face below it by actually having it attached to the mesh. What would be the best way of doing this?

I've tried to bridge the bottom edgeloop to the face however this did not work. I've been looking all over google to figure out how to do this but my blender terminology is next to non-existant so I wouldn't know exactly what key terms to be searching for to begin with.

Comment: very hard to say, please share your file or at least show different pictures

Comment: What does "best" mean? There are several ways.

Comment: Whatt is the reason to attach meshes one to another at all? Geometry shouldn't be connected if one object is just staying on another (and not only in those cases). Depends also on the purpose of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the boolean modifier set to add and then fix the topology manually using the knife tool

Comment: This was my first attempt however it doesn't seem to cut properly. If it cut I would just bridge the vertices to the newly made hole. I can try to perform this again and post a screenshot as to what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your modeling shouldn't be real life perfect unless you are planning to animate it,

Just cut a hole with boolean modifier and place the stick in it.